# Same program GCC crashes but msvc works

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++

I have written a program in C to lower a string when compile it in gcc, it crashes when run. 
But in MSVC program run smoothly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *strlower(char *s){
    for ( ; *s; ++s) *s = tolower(*s);
    return (char *)s;
}

int main(){
    char *c = "HELLO";

    strlower(c);
    printf("%s",c);
    return 0;
}
```

if variable `c` is array then program works in both compiler. Why not work when using pointer in gcc ?

Comment: Modifying a string literal gives undefined behaviour.   When behaviour is undefined, anything is allowed to happen, including different behaviours from different compilers.  Both compilers are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C all string literals are *read only* arrays of characters. Trying to modify a string literal leads to *undefined behavior*. That's the reason you should only use `const char *` when having pointers to string literals.

Try to use your own array instead:

```
char c[] = "HELLO";
```